# Error deleting FileTable - HRESULT = '0x80070490'

Tags: sql-server-2012, filetable

When trying to delete a FileTable, the following error occurs:

> Message 33405, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
>   Error during operation on an object table Discard FileTable. (HRESULT = '0 x80070490 ').

Comment: Awesome. An undocumented message number. Can you reproduce this in a small example? It may very well be a bug in SQL Server.

Comment: I'm trying to delete a table type FileTable (SQL Server 2012). When I do drop displays this message.

Comment: Does this happen only for a particular database, or does it also happen if you create a new database and try to drop a FileTable from it?

Comment: @JonSeigel This happens with a specific database. Began to happen when trying to stop the database and canceled before completing.

Comment: Okay, what do you mean by "stopping the database?" Do you mean shutting down the instance of SQL Server?

Comment: Set database as offline.

Comment: Okay. Have you run [`DBCC CHECKDB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064%28v=sql.110%29.aspx/html) on this database? It sounds like it may have been corrupted by cancelling that operation.

Comment: Not yet, but I'll run. If you find something new warning here.

Comment: @jon-seigel I ran the DBCC CHECKDB and returned no errors, performed first CHECKTABLE and then CHECKDB. Any idea what it might be?

Comment: I don't know. It may be a bug, or the database is corrupt in a way that `CHECKDB` doesn't detect. Consider contacting Microsoft Product Support.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the support, I'll contact Microsoft Product Support and report here the solution.

Comment: That would be great, since the message number you gave appears to be undocumented. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the urgency we do not expect a return of support from Microsoft, but it seems that the error occurred due to attempt to put the database offline.

We solve the error as follows:

*Since we had a base equal to the base model which showed the error, made ​​the copy of the data base with an error (except FileTable) for the base model and recreate the FileTable. It was in this way that we solve.*

Because we applied the solution before the return of support, they could not diagnose prescision.

Comment: Oh well, at least you got it fixed somehow. Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on stackoverflow with the same issue.  The solution there solved it for me. (Rename the Filestream Directory Name to something unique.)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777357/sql-server-2012-filestream-an-error-occurred-during-the-drop-table-operation-o